# Functions in $\mathcal{B}=C[0,1]$ that does not have finite derivative at any point - generic subset $G$ of $\mathcal{B}$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, derivatives

I am studying a demonstration that the set of functions in $\mathcal{B}=C[0,1]$ that does not have finite derivative at any point is a generic subset $G$ of $\mathcal{B}$ (ie, dense and intersection of countable open set).

For this ,the author takes $u_{\psi}^n(t,h)=|\psi(t+h)-\psi(t)|-n|h|$ and

$A_n=\{\psi\in \mathcal{B}:\qquad\forall t\in I\qquad\exists h \qquad \text{s.t.} \qquad u_{\psi}^n(t,h)>0\}.$

He states that:

> $\psi \in \cap_{n=1}^\infty A_n\implies \psi \in G$

But I could not understand this, because the existence of a $h$ is not "local" as the ideia of derivative...

Many thanks for any help!

Comment: If for a given $t$ the $h=h_n$ that certify that $\psi\in\cap_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ were to accumulate at some point $a\neq0$, then $\psi$ wouldn't be continuous at $t+a$ because it would have to be unbounded near that point.

Comment: Perfectly... Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that a continuous function on $[0,1]$ is bounded.

Fix any $\psi \in \cap_{n=1}^\infty A_n$. Let $M=\max_{t\in [0,1]} |\psi(t)|$. 
For every $t\in [0,1]$ and for every $n$, there exists $h_n$ such that
$$(*)= |\psi(t+h_n) - \psi(t)|>n|h_n|.$$

On the other hand, $(*) \le 2M$, and therefore

$$|h_n|\le \frac{2M}{n} \to 0$$.